# I can haz no package-private class in Scala?

Tags: scala

Sorry for the catchy title. ;-)

I want to create a package-private class with a package-private method in Scala, so my class looks somewhat like this:

```
package net.java.truevfs.ext.pace

import ...

private[pace] abstract class AspectController(controller: FsController)
extends FsDecoratingController(controller) {

  private[pace] def apply[V](operation: => V): V

  ... // lots of other stuff
}
```

However, if I use javap to check what the Scala compiler effectively creates, I get something like this:

```
$ javap -classpath target/classes net.java.truevfs.ext.pace.AspectController
Compiled from "AspectController.scala"
public abstract class net.java.truevfs.ext.pace.AspectController extends net.java.truevfs.kernel.spec.FsDecoratingController implements scala.ScalaObject{
    public abstract java.lang.Object apply(scala.Function0);
    ...
}
```

This means that although the Scala compiler might respect the access restrictions, I could still call this class from any Java code, which is a clear encapsulation violation.

Am I missing something?
Is there a way to make this work as intended?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to @Régis' answer, the reason Scala compiler doesn't make the class package-private is because by Scala rules it *can* be accessed from other packages: namely, subpackages of `net.java.truevfs.ext.pace`. E.g.

```
package net.java.truevfs.ext.pace.subpackage
import net.java.truevfs.ext.pace.AspectController

class Subclass extends AspectController { ... }
```

is legal in Scala, but in Java classes from `net.java.truevfs.ext.pace.subpackage` can't access package-private classes from `net.java.truevfs.ext.pace`.

Comment: Well, this actually means that the concept of a package-private class does not exist in Scala at all. Too bad, because for me it has been a primary element of my Java tool set to foster encapsulation (I understand that this protection only works at the language level anyway).

Comment: I cannot accept both answers, so I chose this one because it explains why the Scala compiler cannot declare the access modifier of the generated code package-private - this would not work with the Scala semantics of access modifiers.

Answer (score 10):

You are not missing anything.
Many of the access restricitons in scala have no equivalent in java nor at the jvm level. The additional information is obviously right there in the .class file, but is there as custom annotations that only the scala compiler will interpret.
The scala object model can only partly be matched to the jvm object model, and a java compiler will only see this partial model.
I'd say that the match is pretty close and the scala compiler does a very good job at java interoperability, but nothings's perfect.

Comment: I thought so and recognized the @scala.reflect.ScalaSignature annotation on the class. What worries me though is that this is a clear violation of encapsulation and makes using access modifiers completely pointless as long as you can call anything from Java code.

Comment: Well, "pointless" to the same degree that access modifiers in general are pointless, since you can always bypass them via reflection/pointers.

Comment: I would not go as far as say that you can call "anything" from java. If you make `apply` plain private (as opposed to private to `pace`) then you'll see that the method is indeed marked private in the .class file. This is because the concept of a private method in scala and in java are exacttly the same, so the compiler can mark it as private. On the other hands, the concept of a method private to a package simply doe not exist in java/the jvm.

Comment: Also, @themel is quite right regarding the question of whether access restrictions are pointless or not. Access restrictions != security. It's merely a pretty helpful tool (based on trust) that you use to *help* achieve proper encapsulation for the sake of good engineering. But they can almost never be totally enforced. In java, the trustee is the jvm (rather than just a compiler) which is a good thing, but (stretching a bit) what if I load your class in a non compliant jvm that does not check access? Or in native code, if I access some private field though a pointer?.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a 100% correct answer...

You can make a package object if I want to do some fancy stuff in there with a private class. The package object is accessed like any other package. 
The class MyClass is package private to that package object. 
It's not package private however.

```
package object com.jasongoodwin.foo {
  private class MyClass

  class AnotherClass {
    val myClass = new MyClass
  }
}
```